# Inkscape: How to partly remove a stroke with a different object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, path, stroke, fill

Imagine you have a simple rectangle without fill but with a solid stroke:
[image: Rectangle]

Now I want to "remove" some small parts of this black stroke. Therefore I created a second object with the desired shape and layered it above the intial rectangle to cover the undesirable parts:

[image: Exclude parts of the stroke with an other rectangle.]

The red rectangle should "remove" all the parts from the black stroke covered by it. I tried this with the function "exclude" in Inkscape, but it didn't work - the stroke is still there.

---

Where is my mistake? Do I have to convert something first, e.g. `object to path` or something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Draw the black stroked rectangle.
2. Click *Path > Stroke to Path*. This will turn the outline from a stroke into a filled closed path (with no stroke set).
3. Draw the red rectangle
4. Select both black outlined shape and the red rectangle. Holding down Shift while clicking with the Select tool allows multiple selections.
5. Click *Path > Difference*[image]